# Keyword 'this' is not available when passing it to child form

Tags: c#, winforms, parent

I have three forms, where one of them is the parent and the other two are the children. The reason I'm doing this is so that the parent form can reference the children, and vice versa (I actually ran into a infinite recursion error before doing this, but all gone).

I have written the code as below:

```
public partial class PerfilAcesso : Form
{
 // this is the parent
     BDE bdeForm = new BDE(this); //error line
     Workshop workshopForm = new Workshop(this); //error line

// rest of the info
}


public partial class Workshop : Form
{
    // this is one child
    PerfilAcesso perfilAcesso;

    public Workshop(PerfilAcesso parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        perfilAcesso = parent;
    }
}

public partial class BDE : Form
{
    // this is another child
    PerfilAcesso perfilAcesso;

    public BDE(PerfilAcesso parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        perfilAcesso = parent;
    }
}
```

However, it won't compile, because it gives the following error

> Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

at lines 4 and 5, where I pointed out.

I tried setting the property `IsMdiContainer` in the parent form to `true`, but it didn't work.

Could someone give me any directions as to what I'm doing wrong? I've gone through questions about creating a parent/child form, and they all show the same.

Comment: Use the constructor, then you can use `this`

Comment: @Rango thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not available in field initializations. You will need to move the initialization to a constructor if you need to use `this`:

```
public partial class PerfilAcesso : Form
{
     public PerfilAcesso () 
     {
        bdeForm = new BDE(this); 
        workshopForm = new Workshop(this); 
     }
     BDE bdeForm;
     Workshop workshopForm;
}
```